# How can I create the same skeletal animation to different meshes?

Tags: animation, three.js, blender

I am trying to create the same skeleton animation from a mesh to a different mesh. So I deleted the first mesh ([mesh1](http://threejs.org/examples/models/skinned/marine/marine_anims.blend)), kept the skeleton (which already has skeletal animation) and then, imported the second mesh ([mesh2](http://threejs.org/examples/models/skinned/UCS/umich_ucs.js)) as an .obj file (converted this .js file into an .obj file, using the [three.js editor](http://threejs.org/editor)). I scaled, rotated and changed location of the second mesh so it fits the skeleton. Then, I did the process of rigging (I selected the mesh + shift + selected the armature, then clicked "ctrl + P" to create parenting). And it worked, the second mesh was animated according to the skeletal animation of the first mesh. Nevertheless, when I try to export this mesh to three.js as a skeletal animation (I chose pose mode, because when I choose rest mode, it gives me error), the mesh is displayed in a messy way and not with its normal shape. How can I fix this? The javascript code I used is shown below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="models/three.js"></script>

        <script>

                var scene, camera, light, renderer, objeto, animation1;

                var loader, model;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75,  window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x666666 ) );

                light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xdfebff, 1.75 );
                light.position.set( 50, 200, 100 );
                light.position.multiplyScalar( 1.3 );

                light.castShadow = true;
                //light.shadowCameraVisible = true;

                light.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
                light.shadowMapHeight = 1024;

                var d = 300;

                light.shadowCameraLeft = -d;
                light.shadowCameraRight = d;
                light.shadowCameraTop = d;
                light.shadowCameraBottom = -d;

                light.shadowCameraFar = 1000;
                light.shadowDarkness = 0.5;

                scene.add( light );


                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


                camera.position.z = 5;


                loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();  
                loader.load( 'models/marine_anims_morph.json', addModel );


                function addModel( geometry,  materials ){

                    materials[0].skinning = true;

                    objeto = new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));

                    objeto.position.y = -1.5;

                    objeto.rotation.y = 3.14;
                    objeto.position.x = 0.5;

                    objeto.scale.x = 0.02;
                    objeto.scale.y = 0.02;
                    objeto.scale.z = 0.02;


                    animation1 = new THREE.Animation (objeto, geometry.animations[0]);
                    animation1.play();

                    scene.add(objeto);
                }

                var prevTime = Date.now();

                function render () {
                    if ( animation1 ) {
                        var time = Date.now();
                        animation1.update((time - prevTime)/10);
                        prevTime = time;
                    } 
                }


                function animate(){
                    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                    render();
                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                }

                animate();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't remember exactly but if you still struggle with this you could test what happens when you have the meshes and armatures at origo.

Comment: They are exactly at the origin (0,0,0), with no rotation, and scale at  (1,1,1).

Comment: Did you scale, rotate & move the 2nd mesh in object mode (scene node level) or in edit mode (moving the vertices?). Sounds like a weird problem, I'm out of ideas just based on the description -- if you can share the blend, may be possible for me or someone else to help.

Comment: I edited the 2nd mesh in object mode. I have just edited my post with the files I used.

Comment: What versions of three.js and the exporter are you using? Could you describe the export procedure? I was unable to repeat this with current dev version of both so far: for the blend in your mesh1 link, I can export it ok otherwise but it doesn't show when skinning is enabled. Without skinning it shows ok, but with skinning I can't see the mesh anymore. The skeleton helper shows and plays back the animation ok though.

Comment: I used the release 71. Before exporting, I created a material for the mesh, applying some color to it. Then, you select only the mesh and click File>Export>Three.js (.json). In the export options, I selected "GEOMETRY": Vertices, Faces, Normals, UVs, Bones, Skinning, "Shading": Face Materials, "Animations": Skeletal Animations (Pose), Embed animation.